# Error on building application

Tags: android-studio

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the
>   google-services plugin (information about the latest version is
>   available at
>   https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/)
>   or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.0.2.

I'm always having this problem while I'm using firebase and GMap to my application.

Comment: add your app build.gradle here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure something out, my problem solve by changing the dependencies on firebase and appcompat version. Firebase dependencies should all the in the same version and just try other version in appcompat until it is compatible to firebase.